# Normalized Device Coordinates

Tags: graphics, 2d, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I'm writing a library that deals with 2D graphical shapes.

I'm just wondering why should my coordinate system range from **[-1, 1]** for both the x and y axis
[image]

instead of **[0, width]** for x and **[0, height]** for y ?
[image]

I went for the latter system because I felt it was straight forward to implement.

Comment: Why not Y have Why increase as it moves downwards as it does in screen space?  Even simpler on the math.  This is the reason we have screen and world space transformations so that we can use whatever coordinate system makes sense per object.

Comment: if I will use only your library, how could I write a program which will show the same image on different resolutions without normalzied coordinates?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I'm not really sure what you mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Jim Blinn's *A Trip Down The Graphics Pipeline*, p. 138.

> Let's start with what might at first seem the simplest transformation: normalized device coordinates to pixel space. The transform is

```
s_x * X_NDC + d_x = X_pixel
s_y * Y_NDC + d_y = Y_pixel
```

> A user/programmer does all screen design in NDC. There are three nasty realities of the hardware that NDC hides from us:
>
> 1. The actual number of pixels in *x* and *y*.
> 2. Non-uniform pixel spacing in *x* and *y*.
> 3. Up versus down for the *Y* coordinate. The NDC-to-pixel transformation will invert *Y* if necessary so that *Y* in NDC points up.
>
> ...

```
s_x = ( N_x - epsilon ) / 2
d_x = ( N_x - epsilon ) / 2

s_y = ( N_y - epsilon ) / (-2*a)
d_y = ( N_y - epsilon ) / 2

epsilon = .001
a = N_y/N_x  (physical screen aspect ratio)
```