# Calcluation of viewport coordinates

Tags: vector, graphics, coordinates, viewport

I read an article about normalized device coordinates (on the german DGL wiki) and the following example is provided:
"Let's consider that we had a Viewport with dimensions 1024 pixel(width) and 768 pixel height. A point P with absolute, not normalized, coordinates P(350/210) would be in normalized coordinates P(-0,32/-0,59).These coordinates can now be projected on a Viewport (800x600) just by multiplying the normalized device coordinates (similar to vector scaling) with the size of the viewport. In this case the result would be P(273/164).

Somehow I can't understand how one can get to the result provided (I mean 273/164 and -0,32/-0,59  ...could somebody explain to me how to calculate the coordinates?

P.S. : This is the article - https://wiki.delphigl.com/index.php/Normalisierte_Ger%C3%A4tekoordinate

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article is definitely lacking description. I can get you part of the way there; maybe someone with more math can help finish.

According to [this answer](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/170900-Getting-real-world-coordinates-from-screen?p=1201727&viewfull=1#post1201727), the formula to convert non-normalized coords to normalized coords is:

[image: Nx = (Cx / Sx) * 2.0 - 1.0]

[image: Ny = 1.0 - (Cy / Sy) * 2.0]

(where Cx/y = Coordinate X/Y; Sx/y = Screen X/Y; and Nx/y = Normalized X/Y).

Plugging the example's numbers in:

```
Nx = (350/1024) * 2 - 1 = -0.31640625
Ny = 1 - (210/768) * 2 = 0.453125
```

...or (-.36, 0.45).

Reversing this to get the new coords:

[image: (1 + Nx) / 2 * Sx]

[image: (1 - Cy) / 2 * Sx]

```
Cx = (1 + -0.31640625) / 2 * 800 = 273.4375
Cy = (1 - 0.453125) / 2 * 600 = 164.0625
```

Note that the Y value doesn't match. This is probably because my calculation doesn't account for the aspect ratio, and it should be since these screens have a .75 aspect ratio, while NDC's is 1. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15709245/1424869) may help too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  and the calculations ! Now I get it ! :)

Comment: Glad I could help!